# Relational data in react-query

Tags: react-query

I have a REST api which has this endpoint for getting an assignment -

```
'/classes/<str:code>/assignments/<int:assignment_id>'
```

I have created a custom hook for querying an `Assignment`:

```js
const getAssignment = async ({ queryKey }) => {
    const [, code, assignmentId] = queryKey
    const { data } = await api.get(`/classes/${code}/assignments/${assignmentId}`)
    return data
}

export default function useAssignment(code, assignmentId) {
    return useQuery(['assignment', code, assignmentId], getAssignment)
}
```

This works as expected, but is this the right way to deal with relational data in `react-query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code looks right to me. react-query doesn't have a normalized cache, just a document cache. So if you request assignments with a different query key, e.g. assignments for a user, they will be cache separately.

The straight forward approach to tackle this would then be to structure your query keys in a way that you can invalidate everything at the same time.